# Integrability of function and its Fourier transform implies differentiabilty

Tags: real-analysis, fourier-analysis, harmonic-analysis

Is the the following  true: "Assume $f\in L^1[0,1]$ and $\hat{f}\in L^1(\mathbb{R})$, then $f$ is differentiable a.e"

Comment: it seams that whenever Fourier inversion theorem holds $f(x)=\int_{\mathbb{R}}\hat{f}(y)e^{2\pi ixy}dy$ a.e. Then $f$ Is differentiable a.e.

Comment: So you require $\widehat f$ to be integrable *on $\mathbb R$*? If so, you should modify your post.

Comment: Yes.thats one of my assumptions

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Theorem** (Bernstein). If $f:\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$ is compactly supported and $C^\alpha$ continuous for some $\alpha>1/2$, then $\hat f\in L^1(\mathbb R)$.

This theorem gives a negative answer to your question, since an appropriate version of the [Weierstrass function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weierstrass_function#H.C3.B6lder_continuity) satisfies the above conditions.

The proof is the same as the proof of [the corresponding result for Fourier series](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/442059/). For the sake of completeness, I modified the proof and included it below.

*Proof*. For $h\in\mathbb R$  write $f_h(t)=f(t-h)$. The Fourier transform of $f_h-f$ is 
$$(e^{-i \xi h}-1)\hat f(\xi)$$
The $L^2$ norm of $f_h-f$ is $O(h^\alpha)$. By the Parseval identity 
$$\int_{\mathbb R}|e^{-i \xi h}-1|^2 |\hat f(\xi)|^2\,d\xi = O(h^{2\alpha})$$
We want to bound $ |e^{-i\xi h}-1|$ from below. There is no uniform bound for all $\xi$, but if we focus on some *dyadic range* $D_k=\{\xi: 2^k\le |\xi|< 2^{k+1}\}$, then choosing $h=\frac{2\pi}{3}\cdot 2^{-k}$ gives good result: $\frac{2\pi}{3}\le |\xi h|< \frac{4\pi}{3}$, which keeps $e^{-i\xi h}$ far away from $1$. Thus,
$$ \int_{D_k} |\widehat{f}(\xi)|^2\,d\xi    = O(2^{-2\alpha k}) $$
By the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality, 
$$ \int_{D_k} |\widehat{f}(\xi)| \,d\xi  = O(2^{k/2})\, O(2^{-\alpha k})= O(2^{k(1/2-\alpha)}) $$ 
and the sum over $k$ converges.

Comment: Is there any converse to Bernstein's theorem? Or at least a proof that the $\frac 12$ is sharp? I found this for the case of the torus/Fourier series https://www.epfl.ch/labs/pde/wp-content/uploads/2020/03/Lecture3.pdf (Thm. 2.1) "We observe that the preceding theorem is actually quite sharp, in that there is no embedding $C^{1/2}(S^1) \hookrightarrow \mathcal A(S^1)$" where $\mathcal A(S^1)$ is the space of absolutely convergent Fourier series, i.e. $f\in L^1(S^1)$ with Fourier coefficients in $\ell^1(\mathbb Z)$)."